# Does the floating ball droid have a name?

Tags: movie, robots, flash-gordon

In the 1980 film *Flash Gordon*, one of Ming's servants is a golden ball that seems to be a droid of some kind.

[image]

It clearly isn't particularly loyal to its master, because as soon as Flash kills Ming, the ball droid congratulates him.

### Does this disloyal ball have a name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the character isn't listed in the end titles, according to IMDB the character is known as...

> "[Ming's Floating Servant](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080745/quotes?item=qt0384421)"

...and was apparently voiced by Von Sydow himself, which would explain why the character does not receive a voice credit, despite speaking twice.

---

The film's [official novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3360604-flash-gordon) isn't much help:

> At that point, the globe which had disintegrated the Lizard Man and Zarkov’s pistol flew into the room and halted in front of Flash. The victors tensed, Flash stepping before them.
>
> “Hail, Flash Gordon, conqueror of Mongo!” said **the globe.**
>
> Shouting with delight, Flash leaped into the air, and pandemonium erupted throughout the courtroom.

Comment: Can I cheat and put "the globe" and claim the credit?

Comment: I feel like "the globe" is more a description than a name. Note the absence of capitalisation.

Comment: Thats globeist. Was a problem in the 80s

Comment: I always called it "the tattletale" since it's the one who stooged off Flash by repeating "This Ming is a psycho." :D